# How does this particular StrPos work in PHP?

Tags: php, magento, strpos

I have the following code. I'm wondering if it's working like I think it is:

```
//Gift Card Redemption
        if(strpos($_order->getDiscountDescription(), 'Gift Card') !== false){
                $order .= 'RGC1*1*'.$_order->getDiscountDescription().'*****';
                $order .= "\r\n";
        }
```

How I think it works: look for 'Gift Card' in `$_order->getDiscountDescription()`, and if it's not false, do something. I don't follow what that something is, though. Any ideas on that?

Comment: suitable platform to ask is:- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. BTW what you are thinking exactly that is happening only. read:- [strpos()-Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: You are correct. It appends data to the `$order` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This basically checks to see if the string literal '*Gift Card*' is contained in the string returned by `$_order->getDiscountDescription()` (i.e. presuming it returns a string...). The use of the operator `!==` and operand `false` is used because the position might be 0, meaning the start of the string. Refer to the warning on [the documentation for strpos()](http://php.net/strpos):

> **Warning**
>   This function may return Boolean **FALSE**, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to **FALSE**. Please read the section on [Booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more information. Use [the === operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for testing the return value of this function.

When that condition is true (i.e. the order description contains 'Gift Card') then the variable `$order` gets appended with the string literal `RGC1*1*` followed by the return value from the call to `$_order->getDiscountDescription()`, 5 asterisk characters, a carriage return character (i.e. `\r`) and a new line character (i.e. `\n`).